# How to Display Message Only for the First Time a User Enters

Tags: redirect

Let's consider that this is my website domain: `ilovestackexchange.com`.

When a user enters the address in the omnibox for the **first time ever**, by what means can I display a ‘Welcome’ and ‘Choose your language’ web page, and then redirect him to `ilovestackexchange.com/en` if he had chosen English.

So, is there a way that, whenever the same user re-enters the web site, he gets redirected to the English home page?

Answer (score 0):

set cookie, e.g. has_seen_message with value "en" (language they choosed), and check for this cookie, show message only if there is no cookie. on 2nd load there will be cookie with value, thats how you can know if user has seen message.

Comment: Thanks. I got the idea. However, I would appreciate if you could show a small sample code.

Comment: Can I ask how to set the cookie value as the name the user enters in a prompt box?